# Master switchery control all child switchery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, switchery

I'm trying to create One Master switchery checkbox which controls all the child switchery checkboxes state

Code is

```js
$(function() {
    // Initialize multiple switches
    if (Array.prototype.forEach) {
        var elems = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.switches'));
        elems.forEach(function(html) {
            var switcherys = new Switchery(html);
        });
    }
    else {
        var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.switches');
        for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
            var switcherys = new Switchery(elems[i]);
        }
    }
});
//Master Switch 
var MasterCheckbox = document.querySelector('.special');
//Master Switch Change State Check
MasterCheckbox.onchange = function () {
    if (MasterCheckbox.checked) {
        //Change all child switchery checkboxes state
        var special = document.querySelector('.chkChange');
        // $(special).attr("checked", true);
        special.checked = true;
        if (typeof Event === 'function' || !document.fireEvent) {
            var event = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
            event.initEvent('change', true, true);
            special.dispatchEvent(event);
        } else {
            special.fireEvent('onchange');
        }
    } else {
        var special = document.querySelector('.chkChange');
        //$(special).attr("checked", false);
        special.checked = false;
        if (typeof Event === 'function' || !document.fireEvent) {
            var event = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
            event.initEvent('change', true, true);
            special.dispatchEvent(event);
        } else {
            special.fireEvent('onchange');
        }
    }

};
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://abpetkov.github.io/switchery/dist/switchery.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://abpetkov.github.io/switchery/dist/switchery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Master Switch</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="switches special" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Child Switch</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="switches chkChange" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Child Switch</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="switches chkChange" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Child Switch</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="switches chkChange" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

1. One Master switchery check box to control all child switchery checkboxes state
2. If one child switchery checkbox state `enable` master switchery checkbox state change to `enable` if disabled otherwise remain `disable`

Problem is that not able to change state of all child switchery checkboxes but only one, can check the code snippet

[Plugin Site](http://abpetkov.github.io/switchery/)

[Github](https://github.com/abpetkov/switchery)

[Working Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/9754kr0q/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT::** *NEW CODE!!!*

```
var animating = false;
var masteranimate = false;

$(function() {
        // Initialize multiple switches
        if (Array.prototype.forEach) {
            var elems = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.switches'));
            elems.forEach(function(html) {
                var switcherys = new Switchery(html);
            });
        }
        else {
            var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.switches');
            for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
                var switcherys = new Switchery(elems[i]);
            }
        }

       $('input.special').change( function(e){
            masteranimate = true;
            if (!animating){
                var masterStatus = $(this).prop('checked');
                $('input.chkChange').each(function(index){
                    var switchStatus = $('input.chkChange')[index].checked;
                    if(switchStatus != masterStatus){
                         $(this).trigger('click');
                    }
                });
            }
            masteranimate = false;
       });
       $('input.chkChange').change(function(e){
           animating = true;
           if ( !masteranimate ){
               if( !$('input.special').prop('checked') ){
                   $('input.special').trigger('click');
               }
               var goinoff = true;
               $('input.chkChange').each(function(index){
                    if( $('input.chkChange')[index].checked ){
                        goinoff = false;
                    }
               });
               if(goinoff){
                  $('input.special').trigger('click');
               }
           }
           animating = false;

       });

});
```

[Updated JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e81r8891/3/)

That was really abstract. There seems like their should be an easier way, but I couldn't find it. Let me know if I need to explain anything.

Comment: Really appreciate your effort and time but actually it's not pretty straight forward, I also have to trigger modal(s) based on master checkbox state true/false, which I did with code in OP, example here http://jsfiddle.net/9754kr0q/1/, the only problem with OP code is not able to figure out how to change state of all child checkboxes according to master checkbox state and secondly if all checkboxes (master & child) are false and any child checkbox state change to true then master checkbox state also change to true......(to be continued)

Comment: I think it's possible that your solution can be used and I still can use modals but only thing left is to change the state of master check box to true if any child checkbox state change to true

Comment: with your solution, modal can be triggered, like this https://jsfiddle.net/e81r8891/2/ using the master checkbox change state

Comment: Now, only thing left is if all checkboxes (master & child) states are false and any child checkbox state will change to true should also change the master checkbox state to true, may be another change function on child checkboxes?

Comment: Another change function on the child boxes can't trigger a click on the main boxes. Because it would fire an event to turn on all the children... hmm. This is a good question.

Comment: Thanks aaalllllllllloooooooooooooootttttttttttttttttttttt

Comment: last 3 days was banging my head with this to work and implemented your solution in live environment and worked like charm, wish can give you more +1's

Comment: Glad I could help out. :)